# Get text between [] and [/ "tag"] in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have the folowing script:

```
[h1]tekst in header[/h1]
[page]
    [p]text here[p]
    [table]
        [p]http://sitename.nl/file.php?get=[nickname][/p]
    [/table]
[/page]
```

now i want to get this result:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => [h1]
            [1] => tekst in header
            [2] => [/h1]
            [3] => [page]
            [4] => Array (.....)
            [5] => [/page]
        )
```

I cant figure out how to do this.
I've tried several preg_match_all options, but i am not experienced with regular expressions.

I apprieciate your help.

Comment: what is the connection between your first and second scripts?

Comment: Oddly enough, the example you give looks like valid XML markup with the exception of [nickname]. Could you just replace [ with < and ] with > and use SimpleXML? Or do you REALLY need to parse it into an array like you're seeking?

Comment: you're basically using a custom html-type language, and regexes are **NOT** suitable for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068